# Select a div based one div class with a child div containing a certain id

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-selectors

I'm doing my own form validation thing for jQuery and I needed to target a specific div based on its child div's id. This is Bootstrap forms structure by the way. So given the following structure:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="myName">
</div>
```

I need to select a div with a `form-group` class, that has a div in itself that has `id="myName"`.

I thought this would've done the trick:

```
$(".form-group .child[id='myName']").addClass("has-error");
```

What's the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**has()**](http://api.jquery.com/has/):

```
$(".form-group").has("#myName").addClass("has-error");
```

Comment: nice. this seems more straight forward and intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have the ID of the child element I will find that first using ID selector then find the `form-group` ancestor of that element

```
$('#myName').closest('.form-group').addClass("has-error")
```

Comment: I was actually thinking along these lines, like _parent reference or something .. or is this better? Thank you very much.